# Why are changes to dynamic value not delivered to all GUI elements as they happen?

Tags: dynamic, button, eventhandler, user-interface

The widget below is just a toy that I put together so that I could ask this question.

```
DynamicModule[
 {c = {0, 0}, a = 1, da = 0.1, f},
 f = -Round[Log10[FractionalPart[da]]];
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[
   GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[c - 1, c + 1], 
    RotationTransform[a, c]]
   , ImageSize -> Small
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic
   , PlotRange -> Transpose[{c - 1.5, c + 1.5}]
  ],
  Row[{
    InputField[
     Dynamic[
      ToString[NumberForm[a, {Infinity, f}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]]
      , If[StringMatchQ[#, FrontEnd`Private`ValidNumberRegex], a = ToExpression[#]] &
      ]
     , String
     , ImageSize -> 50
     ]
    , Spacer[10]
    , EventHandler[Button["\[DownArrow]", Null],
        {"MouseDown" :> While[CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] != {}, a -= da; Pause[0.2]]}
      , Method -> "Queued"
     ]
    , Spacer[5]
    , EventHandler[Button["\[UpArrow]", Null],
        {"MouseDown" :> While[CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] != {}, a += da; Pause[0.2]]}
      , Method -> "Queued"
     ]
    }]
  ]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The widget's intended functionality is to let the user

1. specify, via the input field, a "base point" value for the square's rotation angle (in radians); and then
2. perturb this value (and therefore the square's rotation) in small increments, up or down, by clicking on the buttons.

(The idea is to have the functionality of an "infinite slider".)

---

In the current version of the widget, to perturb the angle by more than a single increment, one can hold down the appropriate button (instead of just clicking it).  This will cause the angle to get updated every 0.2 seconds, until the button is released.

It is *essential* that the square's rotation visibly reflect the current value of the angle value at all times.

Unfortunately, even though the value gets updated repeatedly while the button remains pressed, and this is reflected in the contents of the `InputField`, the square's rotation does not reflect the change until the mouse is released.

---

**Q1:** How come the value in the the square's rotation does not change until the mouse is released, even though the input field reflects the repeated updates to the value, *as they happen*?

**Q2:** How can I have the square's rotation reflect the updates to the value *as they happen*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `Graphics` in `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{c = {0, 0}, a = 1, da = 0.1, f}, 
 f = -Round[Log10[FractionalPart[da]]];
 Manipulate[
  Dynamic@Graphics[
    GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[c - 1, c + 1], 
     RotationTransform[a, c]], ImageSize -> Small, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> Transpose[{c - 1.5, c + 1.5}]], 
  Row[{InputField[
     Dynamic[ToString[
       NumberForm[a, {Infinity, f}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]], 
      If[StringMatchQ[#, FrontEnd`Private`ValidNumberRegex], 
        a = ToExpression[#]] &], String, ImageSize -> 50], Spacer[10],
     EventHandler[
     Button["↓", 
      Null], {"MouseDown" :> 
       While[CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] != {}, a -= da; 
        Pause[0.2]]}, Method -> "Queued"], Spacer[5], 
    EventHandler[
     Button["↑", 
      Null], {"MouseDown" :> 
       While[CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] != {}, a += da; 
        Pause[0.2]]}, Method -> "Queued"]}]]]
```